# Disable logger of specific python module in logging config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using the below logging file and load it via [`fileConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig). I would like to configure the logging behavior of modules that are imported. For example, I want to disable (or set it to some higher log level) logging from `urllib3`. How would I do that?

```ini
[loggers]
keys = root

[logger_root]
level = DEBUG
handlers = root

[handlers]
keys = root

[handler_root]
class = StreamHandler
level = DEBUG
formatter = json

[formatters]
keys = json

[formatter_json]
format = %(name)s%(message)s%(asctime)s%*(levelname)s%*(module)s
class = pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your configuration to something like (these are just additions/changes to you what you posted):

```
[loggers]
keys = root,urllib3

[logger_urllib3]
level=CRITICAL
handlers=root
qualname=urllib3
```